# ClassNotFoundException when deploying Jetty server

Tags: java, eclipse, jetty, jetty-9

I am trying to deploy a Jetty9 app which I have installed following some loose directions given by a client. I have gotten as far as being able to start the server on port `8081`, which kept giving a 404 error when I did a `curl localhost:8081` test.

I then set up `/opt/jetty9/contexts/root.xml` with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"  encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>

<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath">/</Set>
  <Set name="war">
    /opt/jetty9/myproj/myproj.war
  </Set>
  <Set name="virtualHosts">
      <Array type="java.lang.String">
        <Item>myproj.mydomain.com</Item>
      </Array>
  </Set>
</Configure>
```

This all seems ok, but when I start the server, this is the stack trace I get:

```
2021-02-07 12:40:00.536:INFO::main: Logging initialized @344ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2021-02-07 12:40:00.717:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.18.v20190429; built: 2019-04-29T20:42:08.989Z; git: e1bc35120a6617ee3df052294e433f3a25ce7097; jvm 1.8.0_282-b08
2021-02-07 12:40:00.736:INFO:oejdp.ScanningAppProvider:main: Deployment monitor [file:///opt/jetty9/contexts/] at interval 1
2021-02-07 12:40:01.069:INFO:oeja.AnnotationConfiguration:main: Scanning elapsed time=98ms
2021-02-07 12:40:01.215:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2021-02-07 12:40:01.215:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2021-02-07 12:40:01.216:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 660000ms
Loading config from:/opt/configuration.properties
Setting the system to DEBUG mode
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/configuration.properties (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
    at com.cit.common.utils.ConfigurationManager.getContents(ConfigurationManager.java:243)
    at com.cit.common.utils.ConfigurationManager.readConfigContent(ConfigurationManager.java:256)
    at com.cit.common.utils.ConfigurationManager.<init>(ConfigurationManager.java:53)
    at com.cit.common.utils.ConfigurationManager.getInstance(ConfigurationManager.java:79)
    at com.cit.common.utils.DaemonManager.start(DaemonManager.java:22)
    at com.cit.common.utils.ServletListener.contextInitialized(ServletListener.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:957)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:922)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1572)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
2021-02-07 12:40:01.244:WARN:oejw.WebAppContext:main: Failed startup of context o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@6895a785{myproj,/,file:///tmp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8081-myproj.war-_-myproj.mydomain.com-2499359659101806391.dir/webapp/,UNAVAILABLE,myproj.mydomain.com}{/opt/jetty9/myproj/myproj.war}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.cit.common.utils.ConfigurationManager.<init>(ConfigurationManager.java:53)
    at com.cit.common.utils.ConfigurationManager.getInstance(ConfigurationManager.java:79)
    at com.cit.common.utils.DaemonManager.start(DaemonManager.java:22)
    at com.cit.common.utils.ServletListener.contextInitialized(ServletListener.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:957)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:922)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:365)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1459)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:852)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:278)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:545)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:46)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:436)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:145)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:576)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:119)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1572)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1512)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1511)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:490)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:77)
2021-02-07 12:40:01.256:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@49ec71f8{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8081}
2021-02-07 12:40:01.272:INFO:oejus.SslContextFactory:main: x509=X509@8f4ea7c(jetty,h=[],w=[]) for Server@436813f3[provider=null,keyStore=file:///opt/jetty9/etc/keystore,trustStore=file:///opt/jetty9/etc/keystore]
2021-02-07 12:40:01.273:INFO:oejus.SslContextFactory:main: x509=X509@74fe5c40(1,h=[],w=[]) for Server@436813f3[provider=null,keyStore=file:///opt/jetty9/etc/keystore,trustStore=file:///opt/jetty9/etc/keystore]
2021-02-07 12:40:01.322:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@689604d9{SSL,[ssl, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:4430}
2021-02-07 12:40:01.322:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @1130ms
```

What's obviously wrong here is there is no /opt/configuration.properties... But I can't find any file that even references this file, or indeed anything online as to what this configuration should be and its contents? I don't know jetty, or indeed java for web at all, I'm trying to do someone a favour by deploying this app but I've been banging my head against the wall for the past days... Any pointers are really appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

From the stacktrace you posted it looks to me like Jetty started up and is starting up the webapplication. This webapplication has some listener configured, and the listener is trying to initialize the ConfigurationManager.

As all this looks like your middleware installation is ok and the webapplication still has needs go ask your client if this is application related.

Comment: Yup this is the same conclusion I got to, currently awaiting confirmation. Thanks, fingers crossed I can configure everything else once they confirm..